# Crontab not running certain segment of bash/sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Basically, each set says "If this VM exists and the users 'admin' is running the script, then perform these set of scripts". When I run the script manually, I have no issues. When it executes through crontab, it will not complete all the way. When I comment out this specific portion, the crontab goes through as it should.

If I manually run the script as sh or bash it goes through just fine.

```
if ( [ "$HNAME" = "VM61" ] && [ "$UNAME" = "admin" ] ) || ([ "$HNAME"= "VM62" ] && [ "$UNAME" = "admin" ] )  || ( [ "$HNAME" = "VM7" ] && [ "$UNAME" = "admin" ] ) ;
```

I believe it is because the limited bash is not recognizing the way I've grouped each pair together. Could someone assist with how I should group it so that bash still recognizes the function?

Comment: Why didn't you write `if [ "$UNAME" = admin ] && [ "$HNAME" = VM61 ] || [ "$HNAME" = VM62 ] || [ "$HNAME" = VM7 ]` instead? But I suspect your problem is somewhere else. Try outputting the environment with `env>/tmp/env.txt` in your script and compare to your interactive environment. Maybe it is as simple as the path not containing a required entry.

Comment: When I would do it through that method it would always kick back an error and would not process correctly.

Comment: Are you referring to the simplified expression or the `env` call? What is the error message?

Comment: The simplified expression.

Comment: Is your interactive shell different from crons? Do you specify the shell to use at the top of your script (in the shebang-line)?

Comment: On shellcheck I put this in and the only suggestion it makes is to use printf in my script for non-alphanumerics, but I don't use them.

When I check /var/log/cron I see that it runs the script, but the output file I associate with it is not going through (nor are the files being deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the cron to run successfully. The issue I had was in the actual crontab itself.

I set mine to:

```
45 23 * * 0-6 ~/crons/clearLogs.sh >> ~/crons/logs/clearLogs.log
```

What I appended to the end to output to a log file (to show the files deleted) was not working correctly. When I removed this line from the crontab the script worked just fine.

I'm not sure why this is occurring as I've got the same exact output as a part of a script, but that's for another issue.